# cons erlang if stament into list

Tags: list, if-statement, erlang

is it possible to us an if statement in a similar way to Haskell in the following structure?

```
replace_with :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a -> [a]
replace_with _ [] _ = []
replace_with f (x:xs) y = (if f x then y else x) : replace_with f xs y
```

I have tried the following:

```
rwith(_,[],_) ->
    [];
rwith(F,[X|XS],Y) ->
    [if F(X) == true -> Y; true -> X, end. | replace_with(F,XS,Y)].
```

but I get the compile response:

```
listsh.erl:40: syntax error before: 'end'
listsh.erl:40: syntax error before: '|'
```

I have used the following which works fine, but am interested in knowing if consing the return of an if statement is possible?

```
replace_with(_,[],_) ->
    [];
replace_with(F,[X|XS],Y) ->
    case F(X) of
        true -> [Y|replace_with(F,XS,Y)];
        false -> [X|replace_with(F,XS,Y)]
    end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct code should be:

```
[if F(X) =:= true -> Y; true -> X end | replace_with(F,XS,Y)].
```

(using `=:=` is more convenient in Erlang but doesn't matter here) but there can be only guard expression in if statement so you have to use

```
T = F(X),
[if T =:= true -> Y; true -> X end | replace_with(F,XS,Y)].
```

or more idiomatic

```
[case F(X) of true -> Y; false -> X end | replace_with(F,XS,Y)].
```

You can even replace the whole function with

```
[ case F(X) of true -> Y; false -> X end || X <- XS ].
```

Note Erlang syntax here, `,` is **separator** of expressions, `;` is separator of clauses, `.` ends the function definition, `end` ends compound expression. It can be inconvenient for someone who comes from other languages.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling there was something special about `if` statements. Case it is! and merry Christmas.